# Question concerning an isomorphism between a module of $\operatorname{add}(M)$ and a hom space

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a $\Lambda$-module of an artin algebra $\Lambda$. Let $N$ be in $\text{add}(M)$. Let $\Gamma:=\text{End}_\Lambda(M)$. Assume further that $\Lambda\cong \text{End}_{\Gamma}(_\Gamma M)$.

> Why is then $N\cong\text{Hom}_\Gamma(\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(N,M),M)$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is clear that the map sending $x\in N$ to the evaluation map $ev_x:\phi\mapsto\phi(x)$ is a homomorphism and injective, but I didn't see how to prove surjectivity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean $\text{Hom}_\Gamma(\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(N,M),M)$? Since $\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(N,M)$ doesn't have a natural $\Lambda$-module structure.

Also, the fact that $\Lambda\cong \text{End}_{\Gamma}(_\Gamma M)$ isn't necessary.

Try proving that the evaluation map is an isomorphism for $N=M$, and then that the class of modules $N$ for which it is an isomorphism is closed under finite direct sums and summands.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\text{Hom}_\Gamma(\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(N,M),M)$. I fixed it. Thank you very much for your answer!